# Data on deportations

Tags: data-request

Is there data on deportations out of the United States? It seems that to get it from the government, you need a freedom of information act request for a specific individual. Are there any open data alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the datasets and charts on deportations from Syracuse University.

http://trac.syr.edu/phptools/immigration/charges/deport_filing_charge.php

Here is how they describe the data they are using:

*Findings are based upon a detailed analysis of the millions of records covering each deportation proceeding initiated by the Department of Homeland Security and its predecessor agency, the Immigration and Naturalization Service, in the Immigration Courts. These individual case records were obtained through requests made by the Transactional Records Access Clearinghouse (TRAC) under the Freedom of Information Act to the Executive Office for Immigration Review (EOIR), a unit within the Department of Justice in which these administrative courts are housed.*